# Keyboard shortcuts for Compare with Latest Version / Compare with Workspace version in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

This was easy in VS 2010, but I can't find the right items in VS 2012.

I'd like to set keyboard shortcuts for the Compare With Latest/Workspace Version context menu items in the TFS Pending Changes view. What's the item I should select in the Keyboard section of the Tools dialog?

Answer (score 12):

(*This was tested with [Visual Studio 2012 Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update)*)

`Tools` > `Options` > `Environment` > `Keyboard` >

Under `Show commands containing` search and assign key combinations to:

**`TeamFoundationContextMenus.PendingChangesPageChangestoInclude.TfsContextPendingChangesPageCompareWithPreviousVersion`** - compares pending item in context to previous version.

**`TeamFoundationContextMenus.PendingChangesPageChangestoInclude.TfsContextPendingChangesPageCompareWithLatestVersion`** - compares pending item in context to latest version.

**`TeamFoundationContextMenus.PendingChangesPageChangestoInclude.TfsContextPendingChangesPageCompareWithWorkspaceVersion`** - compares pending item in context to workspace version.

**`File.TfsCompare`** - open the compare dialog.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755211 leads to "Page not found"

Comment: Apparently that link works only when logged in to MS Connect. [Try this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767545/keyboard-shortcut-not-working-for-teamfoundationcontextmenus-pendingchangespagechangestoinclude-tfscontextpendingchangespagecomparewithworkspaceversion-problem-still-exists).

Comment: Once you've found the pending changes and want to jump to the next/previous difference, you'll find the keyboard shortcuts for those commands under `Diff.*`

Answer (score 5):

For me, this worked:

```
VS > Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Show Commands Containing: Team.Git.CompareWithUnmodified
```

By assigning a shortcut key `Ctrl+\, Ctrl+\` to this command ( *Team.Git.CompareWithUnmodified*) I can now compare my current file (the file that is open in the editor) to the previous version of the file by pressing the shortcut key `Ctrl+\, Ctrl+\`; no need to find the file in solution explorer, then right-click the file then select Compare.

(you can choose your own shortcut key of course)

*Just a note on different behaviour:*

- `Team.Git.CompareWithUnmodified` works for me because I am using TeamExplorer in VisualStudio but I use GIT as the underlying source code repository.
- `Tfs.FileCompare` could also work in other scenarios (i.e. if you don't use Git, but use VSTS or TFS as your source control provider).
- `Other`: the command will be different if you use another source control provider.

Comment: This worked nicely for me in Visual Studio 2019.  I assigned the shortcut key to the: Use Shortcut Key in "Text Editor".

Answer (score 0):

While you have the file open use this combo to compare with Workspace version:

```
Menu, O, C, Enter
```

(This performs `Right Click > Source Control > Compare > Workspace Version`)

If your keyboard doesn't have a [Menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key), do this:

1. Set the hotkey for `File.TfsCompare` to `Ctrl+\` `Ctrl+\`
2. Use the combo: `Ctrl+[` `Ctrl+S` `Ctrl+\` `Ctrl+\` `Enter`